# how to add multi level breadcrumbs with php

Tags: php, breadcrumbs

```
function breadCrumb() {

    global $page_title, $root_url;
    // Replace all instances of _ with a space
    $PATH_INFO = str_replace("_", " ", "");
    // split up the path at each slash
    $pathArray = explode("/",$PATH_INFO);

    // Initialize variable and add link to home page
    if(!isset($root_url)) { $root_url=""; }

    $breadCrumbHTML = '<i class="fa fa-home"></i> <a href=//localhost/pitmis/pages'.$root_url.'>Home</a> | ';

    // initialize newTrail
    $newTrail = $root_url."/";

    // starting for loop at 1 to remove root
    for($a=1;$a<count($pathArray)-1;$a++) {
        // capitalize the first letter of each word in the section name
        $crumbDisplayName = ucwords($pathArray[$a]);
        // rebuild the navigation path
        $newTrail .= $pathArray[$a].'/';
        // build the HTML for the breadcrumb trail
        $breadCrumbHTML .= '<a href="'.$newTrail.'">'.$crumbDisplayName.'</a> &gt; ';
    }

    // Add the current page
    if(!isset($page_title)) { $page_title = curPage(); }
        $breadCrumbHTML .= $page_title;

        echo "<li class='active'>
                " . $breadCrumbHTML . "
            </li>";
}
```

Good day, I have this code above for my breadcrumbs. It is working fine, however, it won't show the folder name or the category name on the breadcrumb navigation. When I visit the category section, it will only show Home | Category Page Name. What I want for it to show is "Home | Category | Category Page Name. Would anybody be willing to assist me with my current code. I just don't know where to modify. Thank you.

Comment: there is the problem in your code. You are doing notinh here. It will not give you anything. `$PATH_INFO = str_replace("_", " ", "");
    // split up the path at each slash
    $pathArray = explode("/",$PATH_INFO);`
 $pathArray will always be empty one.

Comment: Thanks.. change path array to "$pathArray = explode("/",$_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"]);"

Comment: yes after that it will work fine.